# Import system log files into local socket

Tags: command-line, files, sockets

I have coded a single program in spark to receive data from a local socket and capture lines that has the "Error" in them. I write manually in terminal:

```
$ nc -lk 9999
Error: some error message
Warning: some warning message
```

and so on.
I need the socket get the system log information automatically. What ever log file in the system that contains Error messages or Warning ones and then my program can extract Error ones from the socket.

Comment: Your question in unclear. I understand that you want to forward all syslog messages with severity _warning_ and worse to your socket. Is that true? For that you would configure your syslog daemon. What syslog daemon do you run? `rsyslog`?

Comment: Yes, Exactly. and yes, rsyslog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you use `rsyslogd`. Then put a file (e.g. `my-forward.conf`) with the following content into `/etc/rsyslog.d/`:

```
if ( prifilt("*.warning") ) then {
    action(type="omfwd" protocol="tcp" target="127.0.0.1" port="9999")
}
```

and restart the syslog daemon:

```
systemctl restart rsyslog
```

This will forward the syslog messages for all facilities with severity *warning* and worse via TCP to 127.0.0.1:9999.