# Problem in reading from socket

Tags: command-line, python, files, sockets

I have a spark streaming program, that reads data from a socket I have craeted using:

```
nc -lk 9999
```

The program reads the data from socket and exclude the "Error" messages. When I write manually in socket, it works fine.
I have created a python script that prints "Error" messages frequently. I will save the result in a file using:

```
stdbuf -oL python my_script.py &>> my_file.txt
```

and read the file from the socket:

```
nc -lk 9999 | tail -f my_file.txt
```

Every thing is ok, the socket will read data from file while the file is being updated on the background, But the problem is that my spark program doen't capture the "Error" messages.
As a summary:
when I write manually "Error" messages in socket, spark capture them,
But it won't capture "Error" message generated by python script from socket.
Actually the program doesn't work if I read file from socket instead of typing in it.
What is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you typed

```
nc -lk 9999 | tail -f my_file.txt
```

means: Take the output of `netcat` and pipe that to `tail -f my_file.txt`. But `tail` doesn't accept any input, it merely watches the file `my_file.txt`. Try

```
tail -f my_file.txt | nc -lk 9999
```

instead, so that the output of `tail` is fed to `nc`.

Comment: You are welcome. Just a note: perhaps it might be easier to use named pipes in your case or (given your [previous question about rsyslog](https://askubuntu.com/q/1037440/504066)) make `rsyslog` directly write to `my_file.txt` instead of a socket. Just an idea. But perhaps I didn't fully understand your setup.

Comment: Nice idea my friend, your answer to my previous question has greatly worked. As I need to generate stream of messages in a short time, I have used this script to do that instead of `rsyslog`. Thank again